# BIRT Eclipse - No records when previewing results

Tags: eclipse, birt, maximo, data-integration

I have the following code in my open script for my dataset:

```
    maximoDataSet = MXReportDataSetProvider.create(this.getDataSource().getName(), this.getName());
maximoDataSet.open();

var sqlText = new String();

// Add query to sqlText variable.
sqlText = "select workorder.wonum, workorder.description, workorder.worktype, workorder.location, workorder.pluspcustomer"
+ "from workorder"
// Include the Maximo where clause
//+ " where " + params["where"]
;

maximoDataSet.setQuery(sqlText);
```

I have the following code in my fetch script for my dataset:

```
if (!maximoDataSet.fetch())
    return (false);

// Add a line for each output column
// The specific get method should match the data type of the output column.
row["wonum"] = maximoDataSet.getString("wonum");    
row["description"] = maximoDataSet.getString("description");    
row["worktype"] = maximoDataSet.getString("worktype");
row["location"] = maximoDataSet.getString("location");
row["pluspcustomer"] = maximoDataSet.getString("pluspcustomer");

return (true);
```

However when I try to add my outputs rows and preview result, no results are shown. I am connected to the database because other reports are doing so successfully.

Comment: never mind, forgot to add a space for the string in the select statement

Comment: you should download the Maximo BIRT report development guide. There is a chapter on debugging. This gives you lots of helpful output to spot these annoying things much faster.